# Behaviour Space Output .csv file Change

Tags: netlogo

I wish get the behaviour space output of format table removing information other than just the variables,reporters and run-number.
The output still being .csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the top 6 lines of the file. If you're trying to automate this in a bash script or something, you can do:

```
tail -n +7 experiment-table.csv > trimmed-experiment-table.csv
```

Comment: This should follow after the jobscript of headless netlogo right? Won't I need to specify the path too?